# Avoid double, identical arguments in IF

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, number-formatting, google-sheets-formula

This image illustrates a budget, where the values for `Yearly`, `Quartly`, `Monthly` etc. are divided down to their per-month value and then summed up:

[image]

If nothing has been typed, then I don't want to see a `0`. Instead, I just want the field kept empty. As shown in row 4.

Therefore I use an `IF`, where I first check if the calculation gives zero, `A2/12+B2/3+C2>0`. If it doesn't, then I show the result of `A2/12+B2/3+C2`; else, nothing is shown: `" "`.

```
=IF(A2/12+B2/3+C2>0 ; A2/12+B2/3+C2 ; " ")
```

**My question is if I can avoid having the calculation twice in the formula?** `A2/12+B2/3+C2` is written twice. In my actual scenario, I have some quite large calculations, and it seems quite tedious and error-prone that when I have to fix something in the calculation, then I have to copy/paste it so it is identical in both places in the formula.

Is there are a smarter way to achieve this? A smarter way to perform a calculation but avoid the zero-case? A way that does not include duplicating the calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `IF` approach it's unavoidable, but there are different ways like for example:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(""&(A2/12+B2/3+C2); "^0$"; )
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest approach here is not to use formulas or `IF` statements at all. I'd recommend the number formatting approach, which allows you to *display* the values in different ways. 
You can find it here in `menu format > number > more formats > custom number format`) and use it like so:

```
#,##0.00_);"("#,##0.00")";""_)
```